# Ext Js 4 Grid Reconfigure on a fly

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Ext Js 3 was method reconfigure() to change configuration on a fly. In Ext JS 4 i didn't find such method. Anybody know way to reconfigure grid on a fly ? For example to change tbar, bbar, store etc.

Comment: Did you try to use .apply() method on the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconfigure exists on Ext.grid.Panel.  I suspect it still exists in EXT 4 for the others as well...

reconfigure( Ext.data.Store store, [Object] columns ) : void

Reconfigures the table with a new store/columns. Either the store or the columns can be ommitted if you don't wish to change them.
Parameters

```
store : Ext.data.Store

(Optional) The new store.
columns : [Object]

(Optional) An array of column configs
```

Returns

```
void
```

(source: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel )

Comment: Thanks but i asked my question when only first preview was . There are now such method in first preview.